# Proper way to stream Elastic Beanstalk + Springboot logs to AWS ELK

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

It appears there are at least 3 ways to logs from a SpringBoot deployment withing EC2+Beanstalk to AWS ELK - logstash, Cloudwatch, Kinesis and potentially S3 upload.

Is there a preferred way to accomplish this? Cloudwatch seems the most straight forward, however it adds Cloudwatch to the equation which wouldn't be required with logstash if I am understanding correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Logstash (or better, fluentd) is the only of those options that doesn't incur additional costs. Even if you upload to S3, you still need logstash or fluentd to read from S3 and input into ELK. Cloudwatch logs are really expensive for what it provides. Kinesis is only needed if you have extremely high log volume.

Comment: The only time you should ever use CW logs is when you are forced to (eg lambda).